# Laravel 5.4 OrderBy through a relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5, foreach, relationship

I´m triying to order by name through a relationship hasMany. If I order in second foreach, doesn't work, I´m understand that I have to do that on the first foreach but How can I do that?
Maybe I can do that in the Controller but I don´t know how. This is my code:

In the view:

```
@foreach($data['tags'] as $tag)
        <tr>

            <td>{!! date('d-m-Y', strtotime($tag->created_at)) !!}</td>

            <td>
                @foreach($tag->langs()->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get() as $tag_lang)
                    @include('panel.partials.list_name', ['value' => $tag_lang, 'route' => 'tags.edit', 'id' => $tag->id, 'name' => $tag_lang->name])
                @endforeach
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

The relationship in Tag:

```
public function langs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LangTag');
}
```

The relationship in LangTag:

```
public function tag()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Tag');
}
```

The controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $data['tags'] = Tag::paginate(25);
        return view('panel.tags.index', compact('data'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function langs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LangTag')->orderBy('name');
}
```

or like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $data['tags'] = Tag::all()->langs()->orderBy('name')->paginate(25);
    return view('panel.tags.index', compact('data'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eager load it with ordering while you fetch tags. Cleaner solution.

```
public function index()
{
    $tags = Tag::with('langs')->paginate(25);

    return view('panel.tags.index', compact('tags'));
}

@foreach($tags as $tag)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $tag->created_at->format('d-m-Y') }}</td>
    <td>
        @foreach($tag->langs->sortBy('name') as $lang)
            @include('panel.partials.list_name', [
                'value' => $lang,
                'route' => 'tags.edit',
                'id' => $tag->id,
                'name' => $lang->name
            ])
        @endforeach
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeesh, but doesn't work. Just nothing happens.

Comment: @nature Can you be more precise? This is just the translation of your code with eager loading added. Have you changed both the controller and view code?

Comment: Yes, I changed both, the controller and the view just like your best clean code. But the result is the same, it's not sorted by name. And yes, eager loading is added.

Comment: @nature can you try ` $query->orderBy('langs.name');` in the eager loading condition.

Comment: This give me an error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'langs.name' in 'order clause'………

Comment: Try this. Change the code in your controller to `$tags = Tag::with('langs')->paginate(25);` and your relationship to `public function langs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\LangTag')->orderBy('name');
}`

Comment: Changed and testing. It doesn't work. The result is the same. It´s not sorted by name.

Comment: @nature Alright. Well i can't really test the code locally. So the best bet would be sort the result collection set. I've updated the answer with collection `sortBy` method. If that doesn't work i'll setup local data and test it out later and update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, it doesn't work either.